# Does Spark data set method serialize the computation itself?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a data set with multiple columns. A function needs to be invoked to compute result using the data available within a row. So I used a case class with a method and created a data set using it. As example,

```
case class testCase(x: Double, a1: Array[Double], a2: Array[Double]) {
    var someInt = 0
    def myMethod1(): Unit = {...}    // use x, a1 and a2
    def myMethod2(): Unit = {...}    // use x, a1 and a2
    def result(): { return someInt }
```

It is called from the `main()` as

```
val res = myDS.map(_.result()).toDF("result")
```

The problem I am facing is that while the code works correctly, no matter how I invoke, **unlike for the other parts of the program**, the above statement does not work concurrently. Irrespective of the number executors, cores and `repartition`ing, only one instance of a method seems to work at time!

Any hints to what I should look at would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

testCase case class should not be mutable, if you concurrently modify the state of the object your program will be non deterministic because of that. What is looking wrong with the few information you are giving is this snippet

```
var someInt = 0
```

that value is probably being modified concurrently by several tasks and I am pretty sure you don't want that.

Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: There is a lot of data that needs to be processed using input fields as shown and none of the row interacts with any other (ie, the tasks are embarrassingly parallel). The function is complicated, the helper methods process data provided (such as `x`, `a1`, `a2`) to help the main method. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: is someInt modified by myMethod1 or myMethod2? if yes, that is the problem

Comment: Yes, the `var`s are updated by one or more methods. Is there a way round for such cases? `case class`es cannot have static or common members. So I do not see any conceptual problem.

Comment: If you don't explain the problem it is difficult to give a fix, what I can tell you is that you should never add a state to a case class in Scala

Comment: So, solution is to make the case class object stateless?

Comment: it's a general functional programming principle that shared objects should be immutable