# Spark w/ Scala way of using multiple heterogeneous columns in a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe with multiple columns of possibly various types. I need to write a UDF that  takes inputs from multiple columns, does a fairly complicated computation and returns result (say a string).

```
val dataframe = Seq( (1.0, Array(0, 2, 1), Array(0, 2, 3), 23.0, 21.0),
                     (1.0, Array(0, 7, 1), Array(1, 2, 3), 42.0, 41.0)).toDF(
                     "c", "a1", "a2", "t1", "t2")
```

Eg: `("c" * sum("a1") + sum("a2")).toString + "t1".toString`

In actuality, the computation is lengthy and arrays have about a million elements. I am fairly new to Spark and would be grateful if a sample code or a pointer to resource (with Scala examples) is provided.

TIA

Comment: Computation is the sum of the length of your 2 array-columns?

Comment: Summation of all elements of the array. Apologies for the vagueness. It's only for proof of concept.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799760/2751573).

Comment: Thank you. But earlier I tried and as warned in the linked answer, I suspect the deserialization caused performance problems that I am trying to solve. Also it does not have examples for working with multiple columns. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169876/does-spark-data-set-method-serialize-the-computation-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here an example UDF:

```
val udf_doComputation = udf((c:Double, a1:Seq[Int],a2:Seq[Int],t1:Double) => {
      // your complex computation goes here
      (c*a1.sum+a2.sum).toString() + t1.toString()
    })

 dataframe
   .withColumn("result",udf_doComputation($"c",$"a1",$"a2",$"t1"))
   .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+---------+---------+----+----+--------+
|  c|       a1|       a2|  t1|  t2|  result|
+---+---------+---------+----+----+--------+
|1.0|[0, 2, 1]|[0, 2, 3]|23.0|21.0| 8.023.0|
|1.0|[0, 7, 1]|[1, 2, 3]|42.0|41.0|14.042.0|
+---+---------+---------+----+----+--------+
```

Note that the variable names of the UDF don't need to match the column names, but the types must match:

- primitives of type `A` map directely to `A`. But there are several valid mappings, e.g. `double` in the dataframe map to either `Double` or `java.lang.Double` etc. But you cannot map to `Option[A]`! So if your input may be null, you need to use corresponding types from `java.lang.*`...
- `array` of primitives of type `A` map to `Seq[A]`, e.g. `array<int>` map to `Seq[Int]`. Concrete type will be `WrappedArray`, so mapping to this or `IndexedSeq` would also work. Important is to know the the runtime type is indexed.
- `struct` map to `Row`
- `array<struct>` map to `Seq[Row]`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.